# Unable to clone meta-openembedded

Tags: yocto

I want to clone the meta-openembedded from http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded using below command,

```
 But i am not able to clone as i got below error

 1:~$ **git clone http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded**(I tried with git and https too, both didn't gave me positive results)


 Cloning into 'meta-openembedded'...

 error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)

 error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)

  error: non-monotonic index /home/akhann/meta-

  openembedded/.git/objects/pack/pack-

  75e1ad6a3c4244686c8428cd7f72053ffe24015e.idx.temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see at available OE mirrors:
https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Mirrors

Comment: Thank You, i took https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded.git